# JQuery - Selecting one value from a drop box, posting a different one

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down box (select) with 10 different values for the user to select.
I want to make it so that the if the user selects one, it posts a different value
when the form is submitted.

For example:

If the values read:

```
'1-high'
'2'
'3'
'4-Low'
```

and the user selects '1-high', I want the form to post '1'.

Comment: Set the option value attribute to 1 and the caption to '1-high' `<option value="1">1-high</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `select` should look like this

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1-high</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4-low</option>
</select>
```

Then to fetch numeric values you use `jQuery.val()` method

```
$('select').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number at the start of a string, you can use parseInt()

```
var val = parseInt($('#dropdown').val())
```